# dropdown optgroup, add optgroup label to selected child

Tags: jquery

I have this dropdown

```
   <select>
       <optgroup label="numbers">
          <option>One</option>
          <option>Two</option>
          <option>Three</option>
        </optgroup>

        <optgroup label="letters">
          <option>a</option>
          <option>b</option>
          <option>c</option>
        </optgroup>
 </select>
```

With jQuery, how can I append the `optgroup` label to a selected child so the results are
'number-one' when user user selects 'one' or 'letters-b' if the user selects 'b'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just write your `<option>` html with the group label?

```
<optgroup label="numbers">
  <option>numbers-One</option>
  <option>numbers-Two</option>
```

But it you need to do it with jquery

```
$('select').change(function () {
  var selected = $(this).find(':selected');
  var group = selected.parent();
  selected.text(group.attr('label') + '-' + selected.text());
});
```